# Reload an static html page but expanding the URL

Tags: html

Let's suppose that I'm displaying a web page whose URL is
www.mysite.com?id=10&name=test
(the URL is always different. It's generated based on what the user has selected in previous pages)

At the bottom of the page I have a button that when is pressed I want the
same page to be displayed, but adding a new parameter in the URL. For example,
the new page would be www.mysite.com?id=10&name=test&**extraparam=myvalue**

Is there an easy way of doing this? I'm using static HTML. Nothing else.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you using static HTML if you are building up a query string?

Comment: You are right...long story. I am writing my own web server in C# (very basic) so I trying to let the browser do most of the stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this with only HTML, and not using JavaScript or any server-side scripting languages, the answer is that it is **not possible**. You will manually have to write out the URL in your hyperlink to include any parameters you would need to include.

Comment: Thanks. I will have to look for some alternatives then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript to append the parameter to the URL:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href + "&amp;extraparam=myvalue";
```

You can do this in the click event of the button.

Depending on what happens behind the scenes, you may want to check that the parameter is not already present on the query string (as you may end up with multiples of it).

Comment: Thanks but I need to do this only with HTML, not javascript.

Comment: @user389884 - That's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to PHP, you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the current file location with query parameters attached to it.

So, if you were on the page `index.phtml?something=1&anything=2` and you place a hyperlink on the page that looked like this:

```
<a href="<?=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>&nothing=3">A hyperlink</a>
```

The link would point to `index.phtml?something=1&anything=2&nothing=3`.

It should be noted that this will not stop duplicate variables from being added to the query string. It will simply keep appending them to the end.

Comment: Thanks but I need to do this only with HTML, not PHP.